# Cannot access table in oracle after creating dblink

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I am trying to create a dblink in oracle but,it is showing me error.

I have a databas **orcl1** and I want to connect to another database etlsr which I  created next database.

Inside this etlsr database I created a simple table name person inside sys and inserted a data.

Now,i again connect to **orcl1** and wanted to connect to **etlsr** database but it was not happening as I tried

```
select * from person@ETLSR;
```

But it throwed me error as:

```
                  *
Error at line 1
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
```

So,i think to create a db link so,I tried :(I tried these from **orcl1**)

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK sales 
    CONNECT TO sys IDENTIFIED BY ashwin
    USING 'SALES';
```

I added in tnsname file as:

```
SALES =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = SALES_PRD)
    )
  )
```

So,when I tried :

```
 select * from person@SALES;
```

I got error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Why is this error coming? Is there any solution for this dblink creation? Can I also access the tables of another database without using dblinks?

Tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: E:\oracle\app\AshwinPC\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

TEST=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =192.168.1.6)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

sqlnet.ora

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: E:\oracle\app\AshwinPC\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Comment: is the tnsnames that you show, is it located on the database server hosting 'orcl1'?  Remember that with a db link, the database using the link is acting as a client to the other database, and so client-related config (like sqnet.ora and tnsnames.ora) must be on that machine, not your workstation.

Comment: i am using both of these database on my same PC. isnt it possible to create fblink in same PC?

Comment: Yes, its quite possbile to have mulitple databases on the same machine, with db links between them.  I was just trying to make sure you understand that the 'client' making the lookup in tnsnames is actually the orcl1 database itself, and so you need to allow for that in locating tnsnames.  Show us the contents of sqlnet.ora, and the value of the parameter 'db_domain'.  These influence how things are looked up in tnsnames.ora.

Comment: ok i have added the tnsnames.ora and slqnet.ora

Comment: @Randomguy - the `tnsnames.ora` you included doesn't have an entry for `SALES`? The entry you showed separately seems to have the wrong service name too (not `etlsr`), but that would give a different error if it was the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that you have multiple databases on the same computer (and, possibly, some other Oracle software), note that most of them have their own `TNSNAMES.ORA` file. If you don't pay attention what you're doing, you might be actually using the *wrong* file. In order to make everything work, you'd have to maintain all those `TNSNAMES.ORA` files which is a tedious job.

Therefore, create a **TNS_ADMIN** environment variable which will point to some directory (doesn't even have to be part of the \oracle\ directories but, e.g. `c:\my_ora_lib`). Put one copy of `TNSNAMES.ORA` file in there and make sure it contains references to ALL databases you use.

Doing so, you'll make every Oracle software product use exactly this `TNSNAMES.ORA` file.

---

As of database link being created "properly" doesn't mean much. You can do it for any non-existent database, but you won't be able to use it:

```
SQL> create database link dbl_wrong
  2  connect to asfasdfj
  3  identified by asldfkj234l
  4  using 'laskjfoiwe';

Database link created.

SQL> select * from dual@dbl_wrong
  2  /
select * from dual@dbl_wrong
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


SQL>
```

Therefore, make sure you used username, password and database that really exist.